# Маппинг BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Заполняю datagridview вот так:

```
_viewRoutes = new BindingList<DatagridViewRoute>(_shift.Routes.OrderBy(r => r.SerialNumber).Select(r => new DatagridViewRoute
{
    DetourKMs = r.DetourKMs,
    Distance = r.Distance,
    FromCityName = r.FromCityName,
    FromCode = r.FromCode,
    ToCode = r.ToCode,
    KGsTransported = r.KGsTransported,
    PalletsTransported = r.PalletsTransported,
    ArrivalTime = r.ArrivalTime,
    DepartureTime = r.DepartureTime,
    IdShift = r.Shift.Id,
    Id = r.Id,
    SerialNumber = r.SerialNumber
}).ToList());



dgv_mainWindow.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgv_mainWindow.DataSource = _viewRoutes;
```

Потом, после работы с визуально частью, удаляю всё из `_shift.Routes` и массивом перебираю _viewRoutes ну и женю их обратно и только после этого сохраняю контекст данных. У меня вопрос, есть ли способ сделать так что бы список(_shift.Routes), из которого я заполняю BindingList так же изменялся вместе с BindingList одновременно? То есть во время изменения данных в datagridview изменяется `BindingList  _viewRoutes`, может ли сразу одновременно изменяться и первоначальный источник `_shift.Routes`?

Comment: Используйте подписку на событие `BindingList<T>.ListChanged`

Comment: @Bulson Точно! Дайте ответ я приму его.